# BeautifulSoup not returning the title of page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I tried to getting the title of a web page by web scraping using Beautifulsoup4 python module and it's returning a string "Not Acceptable!" as the title, but when I open the webpage via browser the title is different. I tried looping through list of links and extract titles of all the webpages but it's returning the same string "Not Acceptable!" for all the links.

here is the python code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


URL = 'https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-is-login-logout-time-tracking-for-employees-in-office-done-by-ai/'
result = requests.get(URL)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
tag = doc.title
print(tag.get_text())
```

here is link to the corresponding web page [webpage link](https://insights.blackcoffer.com/how-is-login-logout-time-tracking-for-employees-in-office-done-by-ai/)

I don't know if it is a problem with Beautifulsoup4 or with requests library, is it because the site has enabled bot protection and not returning the HTML when sending the requests?

Comment: "The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 406 Not Acceptable client error response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is unwilling to supply a default representation." BeautifulSoup has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server expects the User-Agent header. Interestingly, it is happy with **any** User-Agent, even a fictitious one:

```
result = requests.get(URL, headers = {'User-Agent': 'My User Agent 1.0'})
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to debug this kind of issue is to print (or write to a file) the `request.text`. This is because some servers don't allow scraping. Some websites generate HTML using JavaScript at runtime (e.g. YouTube). These are some of the scenarios where the `request.text` can be different than the source HTML we see in the browser. The below text has been returned by the server.

```
<head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html>
```

Edit:
As pointed by DYZ, this is a 406 error and User Agent in the request header was missing.

https://www.exai.com/blog/406-not-acceptable

> The 406 Not Acceptable status code is a client-side error. It's part
> of the HTTP response status codes in the 4xx category, which are
> considered client error responses

Comment: Not true. You did not debug far enough.